# How to limit the number of test threads in Cargo.toml?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have tests which share a common resource and can't be executed concurrently. These tests fail with `cargo test`, but work with `RUST_TEST_THREADS=1 cargo test`.

I can modify the tests to wait on a global mutex, but I don't want to clutter them if there is any simpler way to force `cargo` set this environment variable for me.

Comment: As much as I love duplicates, this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of "Is there any way to tell Cargo to run its tests on the main thread?". This question specifically is asking if there's a way to set the number of threads somewhere in the filesystem so that neither the environment variable or command line option need to be passed. For that question, even setting the number of threads to 1 doesn't work because it's still a separate thread from main.

Comment: There's an [open PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/42684) that proposes to add an attribute like `#[serial]` to the test runner which would cause the marked tests to not run in parallel, but it's anyones guess if this will be accepted.

Answer (score 24):

As of Rust 1.18, there is no such thing. In fact, there is not even a simpler option to disable parallel testing.
[Source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33519)

However, what might help you is `cargo test -- --test-threads=1`, which is the recommended way of doing what you are doing over the `RUST_TEST_THREADS` envvar.  Keep in mind that this only sets the number of threads used for testing **in addition** to the main thread.