# How can I avoid running some tests in parallel?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a collection of tests. There are a few tests that need to access a shared resource (external library/API/hardware device). If any of these tests run in parallel, they fail.

I know I could run everything using `--test-threads=1` but I find that inconvenient just for a couple of special tests.

Is there any way to keep running all tests in parallel and have an exception for a few? Ideally, I would like to say do not run X, Y, Z at the same time.

Comment: There is no way to express that only some tests cannot run in parallel. Those tests should access probably the shared resource through a `Mutex`.

Comment: It sounds like you have "tests" and "integration tests". It sounds reasonable to split up them into two projects and run them separately.

Comment: Yes, this could be a way.. where integration tests need to run in a single thread

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [serial_test](https://docs.rs/serial_test/0.4.0/serial_test/) crate. With this crate added, you put in your code:

```
#[serial]
```

in front of any test you want run in sequentially.

Comment: Recently you can now be serial across processes.

Comment: Worked perfectly with tokio tests for me. This is much cleaner than clumsily jamming a Mutex in there.

Comment: This definitely a super useful crate for dealing with this cleanly.

Answer (score 14):

As [mcarton mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694017/avoid-running-some-tests-in-parallel#comment90349427_51694017), you can use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) to prevent multiple pieces of code from running at the same time:

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.4.0
use std::{sync::Mutex, thread::sleep, time::Duration};

static THE_RESOURCE: Lazy<Mutex<()>> = Lazy::new(Mutex::default);

type TestResult<T = (), E = Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

#[test]
fn one() -> TestResult {
    let _shared = THE_RESOURCE.lock()?;
    eprintln!("Starting test one");
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    eprintln!("Finishing test one");
    Ok(())
}

#[test]
fn two() -> TestResult {
    let _shared = THE_RESOURCE.lock()?;
    eprintln!("Starting test two");
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    eprintln!("Finishing test two");
    Ok(())
}
```

If you run with `cargo test -- --nocapture`, you can see the difference in behavior:

**No lock**

```
running 2 tests
Starting test one
Starting test two
Finishing test two
Finishing test one
test one ... ok
test two ... ok
```

**With lock**

```
running 2 tests
Starting test one
Finishing test one
Starting test two
test one ... ok
Finishing test two
test two ... ok
```

Ideally, you'd put the external resource *itself* in the `Mutex` to make the code represent the fact that it's a singleton and remove the need to remember to lock the otherwise-unused `Mutex`.

This does have the *massive* downside that a panic in a test (a.k.a an `assert!` failure) will cause the `Mutex` to become poisoned. This will then cause subsequent tests to fail to acquire the lock. If you need to avoid that and you know the locked resource is in a good state (and `()` should be fine...) you can handle the poisoning:

```
let _shared = THE_RESOURCE.lock().unwrap_or_else(|e| e.into_inner());
```

If you need the ability to run a limited set of threads in parallel, you can use a semaphore. Here, I've built a poor one using [`Condvar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) with a `Mutex`:

```
use std::{
    sync::{Condvar, Mutex},
    thread::sleep,
    time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Semaphore {
    mutex: Mutex<usize>,
    condvar: Condvar,
}

impl Semaphore {
    fn new(count: usize) -> Self {
        Semaphore {
            mutex: Mutex::new(count),
            condvar: Condvar::new(),
        }
    }

    fn wait(&self) -> TestResult {
        let mut count = self.mutex.lock().map_err(|_| "unable to lock")?;
        while *count == 0 {
            count = self.condvar.wait(count).map_err(|_| "unable to lock")?;
        }
        *count -= 1;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn signal(&self) -> TestResult {
        let mut count = self.mutex.lock().map_err(|_| "unable to lock")?;
        *count += 1;
        self.condvar.notify_one();
        Ok(())
    }

    fn guarded(&self, f: impl FnOnce() -> TestResult) -> TestResult {
        // Not panic-safe!
        self.wait()?;
        let x = f();
        self.signal()?;
        x
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref THE_COUNT: Semaphore = Semaphore::new(4);
}
```

```
THE_COUNT.guarded(|| {
    eprintln!("Starting test {}", id);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    eprintln!("Finishing test {}", id);
    Ok(())
})
```

See also:

- [How to limit the number of test threads in Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44947914/155423)

Comment: Was looking for exactly this. It would be an interesting feature for the Core team to include (preventing some tests to run in parallel). I see this becoming even more relevant with larger and more complex code bases.

Comment: @Dash83 with the upcoming support for custom test harnesses, I expect that such a thing will show up in some new test harness. It's really a niche thing for the core test framework to have.

Comment: That's good to know. For reference, I don't think the feature of excluding tests to run in parallel is that niche. Large code bases that use shared resources often have that requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You can always provide your own test harness. You can do that by adding a `[[test]]` entry to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[[test]]
name = "my_test"
# If your test file is not `tests/my_test.rs`, add this key:
#path = "path/to/my_test.rs" 
harness = false
```

In that case, `cargo test` will compile `my_test.rs` as a normal executable file. That means you have to provide a `main` function and add all the "run tests" logic yourself. Yes, this is some work, but at least you can decide everything about running tests yourself.

---

You can also create two test files:

```
tests/
  - sequential.rs
  - parallel.rs
```

You then would need to run `cargo test --test sequential -- --test-threads=1` and `cargo test --test parallel`. So it doesn't work with a single `cargo test`, but you don't need to write your own test harness logic.

Answer (score 4):

I find it funny that everyone instinctively reaches for the Mutex (including me at first). Then I realised that for most cases, the simplest way to force sequential execution is just to put everything in a function. It's obvious when I say it isn't it?

Change...

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        // ...
    }
    #[test]
    fn test2() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Into...

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test_all_sequential() {
        test1();
        test2();
    }
    fn test1() {
        // ...
    }
    fn test2() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For a real-life example see [ellie/atuin#748](https://github.com/ellie/atuin/pull/748).

Of course there are plenty of situations this solution will not cover. For example:

1. If you are using some kind of testing framework it's going to get a little complicated.
2. This wouldn't work with tests marked `#[should_panic]`: you'd have to either switch to recoverable errors (i.e. `Result`), or test for the logical contrapositive instead.

But my point is, always try the simple solution first. Don't overcomplicate a problem when you don't have to.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the downside that you can't run a single test from the command line, and also when one test fails the rest are ignored. But it is a useful technique to know about, and it's great that you brought it up! You mention Mutexes but they are not good either, because a panic in a test will poison the Mutex. So using the `serial_test` crate seems like the best option. Of course this functionality should just be part of Rust in the first place.